# Object not Disappearing with Opacity

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, opacity

I have a WPF program that shows a web browser control. The web browser control is in an overlay to get it to show up in WPF. I start off the WPF program with the width set to 0 and the opacity set to 0 and it seems to work okay (other than a thin straight line that disappears when you move the form). There is a button that when pressed sets the overlay to visible and the width to 1000:

```
WB_DocPanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
WB_DocPanel.Opacity = 1d;
wbo.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
wbo.Width = 1000;
```

This successfully shows the web browser object. I have another button that does the exact opposite, however, when pressed it still leaves the box where the web browser was. Any ideas how to get rid of it?

```
WB_DocPanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
WB_DocPanel.Opacity = 0d;
wbo.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
wbo.Width = 0;
```

**UPDATE**

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Name="WB_DocPanel" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0" >
  <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="30 10 30 20" Name="_webBrowserPlacementTarget" />
</DockPanel>
```

Is how the doc panel is generated. On the main window opening the following code is present:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wbo = new WPF.WebBrowserOverlay.WebBrowserOverlay(_webBrowserPlacementTarget);
wb = wbo.WebBrowser;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it still leaves the box where the web browser was"?  What is the element type of "the box"?  Does it refer to `WB_DocPanel`?  Also, changing the Opacity of a WebBrowser control does nothing, and in general it is redundant to setting Visibility to Collapsed.

Comment: It is the WB_DocPanel that remains.

Comment: Can you also clarify what the UI element tree looks like for this 'overlay'?  Is `wbo` a direct child of `WB_DocPanel`?  Is `WB_DocPanel` the root element of the overlay?  How is the 'overlay' inserted into the view?